# Book recommendation for Residue Theorem and Applications?

Tags: complex-analysis, book-recommendation, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I'm especially interested in the Applications of Residue Theorem.
I've already tried Complex Variables and Applications by R. Churchill, but I find it very succinct, at least for the part with the Applications of Residues. I'm trying to understand on my own the integration on various contours and some extra examples would be perfect.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *The Cauchy method of residues: Theory and applications*, by Dragoslav Mitronivić and Jovan Kečkić.

Answer (score 1):

You may follow

$(1)~~$"Complex Analysis" by Joseph Bak & Donald J. Newman

$(2)~~$ "[Some Applications of the Residue Theorem (Supplementary Lecture Notes)](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~cain/winter99/supplement.pdf)" by Pawe l Hitczenko